# Android - Pull to refresh within a tabbed fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-listview

I'm trying to make a refresh while sliding down on the top of the listview possible. I followed [this link](http://www.tutecentral.com/android-pull-to-refresh/) to make it work and it does on an activty. But I need it on fragments that are tabbed within a main activity so I cannot as the example shows use this method on my fragments.

Here's the correct code while using an activity:

**TestActivity.java**

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import uk.co.senab.actionbarpulltorefresh.library.ActionBarPullToRefresh;
import uk.co.senab.actionbarpulltorefresh.library.PullToRefreshLayout;
import uk.co.senab.actionbarpulltorefresh.library.listeners.OnRefreshListener;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.app.ListFragment;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;

public class TestActivity extends BaseActivity {

    @Override
    protected Fragment getSampleFragment() {
        return new SimpleListFragment();
    }

    public static class SimpleListFragment extends ListFragment implements
            OnRefreshListener {

        int i = 0;

        private PullToRefreshLayout mPullToRefreshLayout;

        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;

        List<String> list;

        @Override
        public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

            list = new ArrayList<String>();
            int no = 1;
            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
                list.add("Item No :" + no++);
            }

            super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
            ViewGroup viewGroup = (ViewGroup) view;

            // As we're using a ListFragment we create a PullToRefreshLayout
            // manually
            mPullToRefreshLayout = new PullToRefreshLayout(
                    viewGroup.getContext());

            // We can now setup the PullToRefreshLayout
            ActionBarPullToRefresh
                    .from(getActivity())
                    // We need to insert the PullToRefreshLayout into the
                    // Fragment's ViewGroup
                    .insertLayoutInto(viewGroup)
                    // Here we mark just the ListView and it's Empty View as
                    // pullable
                    .theseChildrenArePullable(android.R.id.list,
                            android.R.id.empty).listener(this)
                    .setup(mPullToRefreshLayout);

        }

        @Override
        public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

            adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),
                    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list);

            // Set the List Adapter to display the sample items
            setListAdapter(adapter);
            setListShownNoAnimation(true);
        }

        @Override
        public void onRefreshStarted(View view) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            // setListShown(false); // This will hide the listview and visible a
            // round progress bar

            new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {

                @Override
                protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(5000); // 5 seconds
                        int itemNo = list.size();
                        itemNo++;
                        list.add("New Item No :" + itemNo);

                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    return null;
                }

                @Override
                protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
                    super.onPostExecute(result);

                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    // Notify PullToRefreshLayout that the refresh has finished
                    mPullToRefreshLayout.setRefreshComplete();

                    // if you set the "setListShown(false)" then you have to
                    // uncomment the below code segment

                    // if (getView() != null) {
                    // // Show the list again
                    // setListShown(true);
                    // }
                }
            }.execute();

        }

    }

}
```

I've already tried multiple times to make this method work in my fragment code but I cannot succeed. The code below is a working fragment example without any input of the TestActivity.

**InfoFragment.java**

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import com.example.app.Config;
...
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.Settings.Secure;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class TicketInfoFragment extends Fragment {

    List<Info> ticketInfo;
    TicketFull ticket = new TicketFull();
    private DatabaseHelper db;
    int ticketId = TicketActivity.getCurrentTicketId();
    String androidId;
    String authCode;
    String platform_url;
    int uId;
    View rootView;

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);

        db = new DatabaseHelper(getActivity());
        androidId = Secure.getString(getActivity().getContentResolver(),
                Secure.ANDROID_ID);
        Config config = new Config();
        config = db.getConfig(androidId);
        authCode = config.getAuthCode();
        platform_url = config.getPlatformURL();
        uId = config.getuId();
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_ticket_information, container, false);
        fillTicket();
        return rootView;
    }

    private void fillTicket() {
        HttpReader httpReader = new HttpReader();
        httpReader
                .setOnResultReadyListener(new HttpReader.OnResultReadyListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void resultReady(String result) {
                        JsonHelper jsonHelper = new JsonHelper();
                        ticket = jsonHelper.getTicket(result);
                        //showTicket();
                        fillSettings();
                    }
                });
        httpReader
                .execute("http://aa.domainlink.com:1324/example/API/v1/json.php?auth=example&a=ticket&uauth="
                        + authCode + "&uid=" + uId + "&id=" + ticketId);

    }

    private void readSettings() {
        InfoAdapter infoAdapter = new InfoAdapter(
                getActivity(), ticketInfo);
        final ListView listViewInfo = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.listViewInfo);
        listViewInfo.setAdapter(infoAdapter);

        listViewInfo
                .setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parentView,
                            View childView, int position, long id) {
                    }
                });
        listViewInfo.setEmptyView(rootView.findViewById(R.id.empty));
    }

    private void fillSettings() {
        String dueDate = getString(R.string.noDueDate);
        ticketInfo = new ArrayList<Info>();
        ticketInfo.add(new Info(getString(R.string.ticket_subject), ticket.getSubject() + ""));
        ticketInfo.add(new Info(getString(R.string.ticket_relation), ticket.getRelation() + ""));
        ticketInfo.add(new Info(getString(R.string.ticket_status), ticket.getStatus() + ""));
        ticketInfo.add(new Info(getString(R.string.ticket_priority), ticket.getPriority() + ""));
        ticketInfo.add(new Info(getString(R.string.ticket_created), ticket.getTicketCreate() + ""));
        ticketInfo.add(new Info(getString(R.string.ticket_department), ticket.getDepartmentName() + ""));
        ticketInfo.add(new Info(getString(R.string.ticket_user), ticket.getUser() + ""));
        if (!ticket.getDueDate().equals("00-00-0000 00:00:00")) {
            dueDate = ticket.getDueDate();
        }
        ticketInfo.add(new Info(getString(R.string.ticket_dueDate), dueDate));
        readSettings();
    }
}
```

The BaseActivity that the activity normally requires:

**BaseActivity.java**

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class BaseActivity extends Activity {

      @Override
      protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Add the Sample Fragment if there is one
        Fragment sampleFragment = getSampleFragment();
        if (sampleFragment != null) {
            getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .replace(android.R.id.content, sampleFragment).commit();
        }

      }

      //This method will override by child class. Then base class can get the fragment
      protected Fragment getSampleFragment() {
        return null;
    }

}
```

Posting my failed tries on implementing the activity method in my fragments would not work I guess so I do not post them.

If anyone of you could help thanks alot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android SDK has finally added SwipeRefreshLayout. Maybe you can add this to your layout? 
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/SwipeRefreshLayout.html